# ECB Pointing to Custom ASPX Page - Page_Load Firing Twice

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, aspx

I have a custom edit control (ECB) block which points to a custom ASPX page that has some code-behind. Developed as part of a larger Visual Studio solution.

For some reason the code behind for the page is running twice. This is causing problems with what the page should be displaying.

**Why would the code behind in Page_Load method be running/firing twice?**

**Is this some how related to the issue others have previously faced with event receivers firing twice?**

The simple page markup:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CancelLeaveRequest2.aspx.cs" Inherits="spLeaveBooking.Layouts.spLeaveBooking.CancelLeaveRequest2" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
        You cannot cancel this leave request either because it was rejected, a cancellation request is already pending, you created it a few seconds ago or you are not the person who originally created this leave request.
        <br /><br />
        If you created another leave request a few seconds ago, wait a couple of minutes and try again. If the problem persists, contact your SharePoint administrator.
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >

</asp:Content>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;

namespace spLeaveBooking.Layouts.spLeaveBooking
{
    public partial class CancelLeaveRequest2 : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
                {
                    // Get query string parameters
                    string listGuid = Request.QueryString["ListId"];
                    string listItemId = Request.QueryString["ItemId"];

                    // Get the relevant list and list item
                    SPList list = web.Lists.GetList(new Guid(listGuid), false);
                    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(int.Parse(listItemId));
                    bool error = false;

                    /* Some code */

                    if (error)
                        Panel1.Visible = true;
                    else
                        // Redirect back to the list
                        Response.Redirect(web.Url + "/Lists/" + list.Title);
                }
            }
        }

        private bool DoUpdate(SPWeb web, SPListItem item, string status)
        {
            /* Some code */
        }

        private void SendEmail(SPWeb web, SPListItem item)
        {
            /* Some code */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid pageload function working on each postbacks by `!IsPostBack`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
```

A User control with this master page can also cause pageload execute twice...

check the links for more info 
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785825/page-load-is-firing-twice-in-asp-net-page)
[Link 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ccc75925-3460-497c-8471-fcebecd8d061/pageload-called-twice?forum=vbgeneral)
[Link 3](http://forums.asp.net/t/990627.aspx?Load%20fires%20twice%20)

Comment: Just tried this and it seems that on both occasions it is not a post back, therefore the code runs twice.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you check the links . there are other solution that users have tried . Please go through the links and see if you find something that works

Comment: Yes I tried some of the suggestions, without success. For example, setting AutoEventWireup to FALSE stops the code behind from running all together.

Comment: Try setting AutoEventWireup to true in the @Page directive, then removing Handles MyBase.Page_Load, Me.Load from the Page_Load, in all the solutions files.   see the comment from the post in link 2 

 

I did not set AutoEventWireup attribute to true, but I removed ",Me.Load" and that sovled my problem. Now I am investigating how and when ",Me.Load" was inserted into my code.

Comment: I saw that solution as well, but my `Page_Load` function does not have `Handles MyBase.Page_Load, Me.Load` at the end of it, nor anywhere else in the page source.

Comment: did you try this The problem can be a blank image source that you might be setting programatically

<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="" /> you can fix it by correcting the empty ImageURL for the (asp:Image) Tag to a known value. .. try removing the image tag and the page might load only once. I have no clue that a standard html would make the aspx be called twice. check out this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1401763.aspx

Comment: Saw that solution too, but I don't have any images or any tags with source attributes in my markup. I'll update my question with the markup and code.